# How can I decode these models with Realm?

Tags: swift, realm

I want to use these models both for realm and as codable with Json. How can I do this? As I understand it, Realm doesn't accept it when I use Dictionary.

```
class QuestionContainer: Codable {
    
    var questionCategories: [Question]
}

class Question: Object, Codable, Identifiable {
    
    @objc dynamic var title: String
    @objc dynamic var id: String
    @objc dynamic var questions: [QuestionList]
}

class QuestionList: Object, Codable, Identifiable {
    
    @objc dynamic var id: String
    @objc dynamic var question: String
    @objc dynamic var isQuestionImage, isSectionImage: Bool
    @objc dynamic var imageURL: String
    @objc dynamic var imageData: Data?
    @objc dynamic var sections: [QuestionSections.RawValue : String]
    @objc dynamic var selected: String
    @objc dynamic var correct: String
}

enum QuestionSections: String, Codable {
    case A = "A"
    case B = "B"
    case C = "C"
    case D = "D"
}
```

Comment: Can you please include the code you've attempted? We're not a code writing service and we want to understand where your stuck - and including your code we let us know what part you're having difficulty with.

Answer (score 0):

Your model should look like:

```swift
class QuestionContainer: Object, Codable {
    
    @Persisted var questionCategories: List<Question>
}

class Question: Object, Codable, Identifiable {
    
    @Persisted var title: String
    @Persisted var id: String
    @Persisted var questions: List<QuestionList
}

class QuestionList: Object, Codable, Identifiable {

    @Persisted var id: String
    @Persisted var question: String
    @Persisted var isQuestionImage: Bool 
    @Persisted var isSectionImage: Bool
    @Persisted var imageURL: String
    @Persisted var imageData: Data?
    @Persisted var sections: Map<String, String>
    @Persisted var selected: String
    @Persisted var correct: String
}
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: ```@Persisted var sections: Map<String, String>```I couldn't make it codable.
Error: ```Type 'QuestionList' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable' | Type 'QuestionList' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'```